# Como centralizar um slide?

Tags: css, css3

Estou usando [esse slide](http://upstairsweb.com/blog/basic-jquery-beforeafter-photo-slide-bar) que é antes e depois. A questão é: Preciso centralizar esse slide e deixá-lo responsivo, pois quando jogo o código ele fica encostado no canto esquerdo. Tentei dar um `margin-left`, a princípio centraliza, só que fica horrível no responsivo, não se adapta com o `margin-left` (Mesmo em %).

Comment: Tem como postar o seu exemplo no fiddle ou aqui?

Comment: coloque o seu codigo para facilitar a resposta

Comment: Galera, o link com o código do slide está no post, "esse slide". Estou usando exatamente as mesmas imagens como teste!

Answer (score 2):

Coloque o código do slide entre as tags e olhe se funcione:

```
<center>
    <div id="exemplo">
        ...
    </div>
</center>
```

Tente aplicar o CSS entao, cou considerar o id da div e desconsidere o center:

```
#exemplo{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Na verdade há como fazer em CSS também, mais tente esse aí, qualquer dúvida eu posto em CSS.

Comment: Já tinha feito isso, centraliza, mas não fica responsivo, o slide é 800x600!

Answer (score 1):

Eu não coloquei numa interface para testar.
Mas a lógica é que a `div` pai de todas deve ter `margin:auto`, fazendo com que ela fiquei no meio da tela.

Dentro tem duas `div's` que estão com `position:absolute`, para deixar no meio, aplique `margin:auto`, `left:0` e `right:0`.

Para imagem ficar no meio apenas coloque um `text-align: center` nessas `div's`.

Para deixar a imagem responsiva, aplique `width:100%` nelas.

Outra coisa na `div` pai. Ela tem 800px de `width`, então a imagem vai estourar. Coloque um `width: 100%` e um `max-width: 800px;` para determinar o limite de tamanho para essa `div`.

Teste.

```
<div class="beforeAfterSlidebar">
   <div class="bottomImage"><img src="images/afterImage.jpg" width="800" height="600" alt="after" /></div>
   <div class="topImage"><img src="images/beforeImage.jpg" width="800" height="600" alt="before" /></div>
</div>

.beforeAfterSlidebar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
.beforeAfterSlidebar div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.beforeAfterSlidebar div img{
    width: 100%;
}
.topImage {
  border-right: solid 4px black;
}
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7yuuur Olha aqui um print, nesse exemplo a minha seta está no meio do slide!, meio que mudou o modo do slide, ao inves de ir da direita pra esquerda o antes e depois, tá vindo do canto direito inferior, pro canto esquerdo superior!